# Post values and upload Image to php server in android

Tags: java, php, android, image, upload

I am trying to upload image from android phone to php server with additional values,the method is post
my php file look like this

```
if($_POST['val1']){
  if($_POST['val2']){
     if($_FILE['image']){
      ...... 
    }
  }
}else{
echo "Value not found";
}
```

I am doing is

```
URL url=new URL("http://www/......../myfile.php");
HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setUseCaches(false);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");//Enable http POST
con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+"****");
connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", imagefilePath);
DataOutputStream ostream = new DataOutputStream( con.getOutputStream());
String res=("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"val1\""+val1+"****"+
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"val2\""+val2+"****"
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\";filename=\"" + imagefilePath +"\""+"****");
outputStream.writeBytes(res);
```

my actual problem is values are not posting so first if condition get false and else section is executed that is it give value not found
please help me

Comment: what kind of object is "connection"? Is it the same object as "con" (HttpUrlConnection)? And if you want to pass parameters, there are more elegant ways to do that. Myabe I'm missing something. That res String is too jammed :)

Comment: it is con i have make mistake in writing here but it is con in my real code  thank you for your help

Comment: Please try with HttpDefaultClient.

Comment: Have you been logging the data recieved via the PHP Form to determine whether the problem is in the PHP Handler or the Android Client?

Answer (score 2):

I have found solution of my problem. I am making mistake at line string res=(" .... ");
I have not adding "\r\n" after every content.I have add it and my code working properly

link is very useful for me :
http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME

Thank you sir for helping me

Answer (score 0):

here is a nice article, http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/. It works.