# MultiPartEntity along with plain text in android

Tags: java, android, http, multipartentity

I am trying to send `MultiPartEntity` to the server to upload an image.

I have to send data to the server with a `MultiPartEntity`, The following is a sample request.

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": "12345",
    "primary_account_id": "43566"
  },
  "poster_photo": {
    "title": "photo test",
    "image": *uploaded image 
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Please help me solve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422541/how-to-send-multiple-images-to-server-using-multipartentity-from-android

Comment: Why don't you send it in the format:  MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
   mpEntity.addPart("id", new StringBody("12345"));
   mpEntity.addPart("image", new FileBody(imageFile, "photo test"));

Comment: i tried that but i need to send "id" inside the "user" tag and "image" should be inside the "poster-photo" tag. @YogeshSomani

Comment: @Taruni did you checked my answer?

Comment: @Taruni for uploading image in multi-part check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623507/post-valuse-and-upload-image-to-php-server-in-android/4633474#4633474

Answer (score 3):

There are two way to achieve your goal.

**1)Using JSON**

**Android Side:-** First thing is JSON format can support only string data, so you can add only string data. If you want to add image in JSON format so you have to convert `Image to String`. [Image into bytearray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513976/how-to-convert-image-into-byte-array-and-byte-array-to-base64-string-in-android)

**Server Side:-** Decode byte string and convert in Image.

**2)Using NameValuePair**

**Android Side:-** Used NameValuePair instead of JSON, for this way follow link which HardikJoshi given in comment ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422541/how-to-send-multiple-images-to-server-using-multipartentity-from-android))

**Server Side:-** Change server code JSON to NameValuePair.

I suggest Second Way is easy to implement & understand..