# upload compressed image in android

Tags: android, image, performance, upload, compression

> I have to make an android application, in which user can browse image from gallery or from camera.. the image is then conerted to string and then uploaded to the local server.
>   At the server the image is converted again and stored as an image. Ihave compressed the image but i am unable to upload it please help me

Below is the code..

```
    package com.example.hdfcuploadapp;



import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.app.Activity;``
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private static View popupView = null;
    private static PopupWindow popupWindow = null;
    private static Button buttonBrowse = null;
    private static String compressedImage = null;
    private static Point position = null;
    private static Bitmap imageSelected = null;
    private static String selectedImageRealPath = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         Button buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

         buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



            }
        });

      buttonBrowse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBrowse);

        buttonBrowse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(position!= null){
                    showPopup(MainActivity.this, position);
                }           
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            private void showPopup(final Activity activity, Point position) {

                int popupWidth = 120;
                int popupHeight = 130;

                LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.popup);

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                 popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, linearLayout);

                 popupWindow = new PopupWindow(activity);
                 popupWindow.setContentView(popupView);
                 popupWindow.setWidth(popupWidth);
                 popupWindow.setHeight(popupHeight);

                 int offset_X = 85;
                 int offset_Y = 5;

                 popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
                 popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, position.x + offset_X, position.y + offset_Y);

            }
        });     
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){

        int[] location = new int[2];
        buttonBrowse.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        position = new Point();
        position.x = location[0];
        position.y = location[1];

    }

    public void buttonGallery_Click(View v){

        Intent intent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    public void buttonTakePhoto_Click(View v){
        popupWindow.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
               Intent intent){

        switch(requestCode) { 
        case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
             Uri selectedImageUri = intent.getData();
               selectedImageRealPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
               imageSelected = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImageRealPath);
               compressedImage = imageCompression(selectedImageRealPath);  

                final ImageView imageViewPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhoto);
               imageViewPhoto.setImageBitmap(imageSelected);

            }
            break;

        case CAMERA_REQUEST:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImageUri = intent.getData();
                selectedImageRealPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                imageSelected = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), imageSelected, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), "This is an Image.");
                compressedImage = imageCompression(selectedImageRealPath);

                final ImageView imageViewPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhoto);
                imageViewPhoto.setImageBitmap(imageSelected);
            }
            break;
        }
        popupWindow.dismiss();  
    }


    private String imageCompression(String filePath) {
        File imageFile = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try
        {
          fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile); 
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, baos );

        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

        return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
}



    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri)
    {
        try
        {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: can create a web service in asp.net and use it for image upload, if yes then how and if no then what are other alternatives?? I don't want to use php script at the server..

Comment: For PHP check this answer hope it will help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623507/post-values-and-upload-image-to-php-server-in-android/4633474#4633474    and for .Net you have convert your image into BASE64 string and send it to server

Comment: i have already converted image into Base64 string, But don't know how to upload it??please help me out.

Comment: you can send Basr64 Encoded string as string variable with your soap envelop now on server side web service decode Base64 string and compress it back to image (I have no ideal of .net so don't know how to compress string to image)

Answer (score 0):

```
public  String EncodeToString(Bitmap image)
{                   
     Bitmap immagex=image;
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
     byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
     String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);            
     return imageEncoded;
}
```

make sure that while passing the bitmap to this method try to reduce the size of bitmap as much as possible and if possible run in background thread

Comment: i had already compressed the image..I want to upload compressed image??

Answer (score 0):

```
     Image ivcard = Base64ToImage(vcard);
    //Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(120, 120, ()=>false, IntPtr.Zero);
   // thumb.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "thumb"));
    try
    {
        string x = System.DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
        string ipath1;
        ipath1 = "ma\\imagesc1" + x + ".jpg";

        ivcard.Save(Server.MapPath(ipath1), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    catch { }



private Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
    // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0,
                                     imageBytes.Length))
    {
        // Convert byte[] to Image
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void uploadImage(String filePath) {

   File imgFile=new File(filePath);
    RequestParams requestParamsForUploadImage=new RequestParams();
    requestParamsForUploadImage.put("file",imgFile);        

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.post("URL of server upload file",
            requestParamsForUploadImage, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                // response code '200'
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, org.json.JSONObject response) {
                    //Image is uploaded successfully...
                }

                // When the response returned by REST has Http
                // response code other than '200' such as '404',
                // '500' or '403' etc
                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, java.lang.Throwable throwable, org.json.JSONObject errorResponse) {
                  //Failed to upload
                }

            });
}
```

As I have used [AsyncHttpClient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.html) library to perform file upload.Don't forget to add it in your project

Answer (score 0):

Compress image to **75%** then upload.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```